# Global variables and sessions in Developer Studio

Tags: eclipse, progress-4gl, openedge

Now it starts a session for each file you run. Is there any way to run two files using the same session (and the same global variables) in Eclipse Progress Developer Studio 3.7 (without one file running the other)?

Yes I know global variables should be avoided but that's not the topic.

Comment: Do what you can to replace those global variables with something (anything) else. They are evil...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the Procedure Editor from Developer Studio by clicking the highlighted button.

[image]

The Procedure Editor will contain the currently active file from Eclipse. It is running in the progress process from Developer Studio that is used for compilation of the current project. So all files you start this way will be executed using the same process (as long as you do not restart the OpenEdge AVM).

In the Procedure Editor just hit F2 to execute the file. Note that this will only work for procedure files, not for classes.

Comment: Thank you. This was excatly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the run configuration to use the project avm instead of starting a new one.
That way subsequent runs will be in the same session. 
You'll need to restart the avm to get rid of the context created by those runs

Answer (score 0):

Only if you run it from the char or GUI client, and then it would still be:

```
run prog1.p.
run prog2.p.
```

so there's now way to do this w/out having a "stub" program which runs the two programs in sequence.